# What kind of meta data can we really get our hands on?

Tags: discussion

After looking at this [question](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/496/do-we-need-to-change-voting-patterns), I began looking at votes/views ratio.  I know that we can get some meta data out of the site, but are questions I would like to ask but haven't seen (from A51 for example).

One nice scatter plot to look at would be votes/views ratio, possibly as a 3D graph over time.  I'm also thinking about trying to ask some good test questions in the highly specific field category and pop science category to see if we can watch these trends from starting at the same time.  Of course I might have fouled things up by mentioning that here, so if I do, I'll at least wait a bit.

Answer (score 2):

(It only took three months, but...) Along with all other beta sites in the Stack Exchange network, Biology now has regular data dumps on [the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) (SEDE). Brent Ozar wrote a great post about [how to query the Stack Exchange database](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/how-to-query-the-stackexchange-databases/) which you can use to get yourself acquainted with the system.

The link to compose a new query on Bio.SE is [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/biology%20stack%20exchange/query/new). The schema is helpfully listed in the table on the right to show you what types of information you can actually work with.